# Interpolation with symbolic variable to speed up numerical integral

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, interpolation

I have the following integral:

$$E(r) = \int^{\infty}_0 e^{-x^2} e^{i\pi(ax^2 - \frac{x}{\Delta})}J_0(r\,x)x \,\mathrm{d}x,$$ where $J_0$ is the zeroth Bessel function of the first kind.

Two problems:

- The result of the integral still has a symbolic variable, $r$.
- Because of the $x$ in the argument of $J_0$, this integral is highly oscillatory.

I would have wanted to make a `Table` of the integrand, and then `Interpolate` it to make the integration faster. However I would not know how to deal with the symbolic variable, and also with the high oscillations.

I know `NIntegrate` is already taking into account the best method to deal with oscillations when it encouters Trig or Bessel functions, but I was wondering whether it was possible to help it even more?

Comment: What are `a` and `Δ`?  Their values are significant, since that exponential factor is oscillatory, too, more so than the Bessel factor probably.

Comment: Your integral seems to come from a Fourier transfrom of a function that depends only on the radial variable. I have some experience on this kind of integrals. I always use FFT in cartesian coordinates, and interpolate the numerical result, unless I was looking for a closed-from of the integral. In this case, maybe [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313928276_The_Optical_Transfer_Function_and_the_Meijer-G_function) could help you... If you provide the function in cartesian coordinates I could assist you further...

Comment: $a$ and $\Delta$ are constants but ideally they also depend on other symbolic variables. For now I can keep stuff simple.
@JoséAntonioDíazNavas, thanks: well the $x$ is the integration variable to I don't think we care about that? $r = x^2 + y^2$ in Cartesians, where this $x$ is different from the dummy integration variable. Can this lead to what you had in mind?

Comment: actually the resulting pattern will be circularly symmetric, so can I not let $r=x$?

Comment: The integral cannot be done numerically without numeric values for α and Δ. Setting them to 1, I can do the integral in a few milliseconds. I don't know if that's fast or not. If the parameters can be significantly different in magnitude, the method might not work or at least not work well.